# How to check programmatically if WP8 device has front facing camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating an app with multiple functionalities one of those needs access to front facing camera. I do not set it as a necessity to install the app in the manifest because I want the user to have access to the other functionalities even if front facing camera is not present. I do need however to notify the user whenever he starts said functionality that front facing camera is needed and it cannot run. How can that be done programmatically?

I have searched around the web and only found ways to exclude devices that do not have a front facing camera. That is not what I need however and I am wondering if it is even possible to do so....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Devices.Camera` class offers information like

```
Camera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.FrontFacing)
```

I've found more info about creating and manipulating cameras **[here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**.

Comment: Thank you sir for your fast reply